# removing dots but not decimal dots

Tags: perl, sed

I have a space delimited text file that contains periods `.` as missing data and periods as decimal separator.  I want to replace all the missing data periods with `NaN` and leave the decimal separators alone - here is an example:

Sample data:

```
1981 12 23 . 4.5 . .
1981 12 24 4.6 7.8 1.2 22.0
1981 12 25 . . . .
1981 12 26 2.1 . 3.1 .
```

Desired output:

```
1981 12 23 NaN 4.5 NaN NaN
1981 12 24 4.6 7.8 1.2 22.0
1981 12 25 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1981 12 26 2.1 NaN 3.1 NaN
```

Any help using sed, tr, perl in a unix environment would be much appreciated

Comment: add leading and trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 6):

This Perl program will do it, replacing any dot without a digit next to it:

```
#!/Users/brian/bin/perls/perl5.14.2

while( <DATA> ) {
    s/ (?<!\d) \. (?!\d) /NaN/xg;
    print;
    }

__END__
1981 12 23 . 4.5 . .
1981 12 24 4.6 7.8 1.2 22.0
1981 12 25 . . . .
1981 12 26 2.1 . 3.1 .
```

That's a short Perl one-liner:

```
% perl -pe 's/ (?<!\d) \. (?!\d) /NaN/xg' input_file
```

Comment: Wow, identical answers, three seconds apart.. we should get some badge for that.

Comment: Force of habit... Besides, who doesn't like warnings? Anarchy, I tell you.

Answer (score 6):

Using negated look-around assertions seems to be a good idea here.

```
perl -plwe 's/(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)/NaN/g;' file.txt
```

In other words, only replace if the surrounding characters are not numbers. It might fail if you have numbers such as: `.1231` (as opposed to `0.1231`). In such a case, you can remove the first look-around.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;s/ \. / Nan /g;ta;s/ \.$/ Nan/' file
```

or if numbers like `.123` don't exist:

```
sed 's/ \./ Nan/g' file
```

Comment: I believe the first one will skip every other `.` because the space between them can only be matched once.

Comment: Oops! I forgot my loop. amended. Thanks @Kevin

Answer (score -1):

Check if the next character after a dot is a space. If it is, add a NaN there.

Comment: A string like "1. " is usually parsed as a valid floating point number, so that might not always work.

Comment: I'd be wary of numbers like `10.`, where the dot specifies that the last digit is significant.

Comment: Will fail for a line such as `1981 12 .` You need to check what is *not* there.